# File upload problem with AWS using Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have deployed my django app through cpanel. Static and media files are correctly served through AWS S3. But when i try to upload a file/pic it is not uploading and shows no error and redirects to home page with the url of the page on which file was uploaded.
Home page URL: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), Upload page URL:[www.example.com/upload](http://www.example.com/upload).

Bucket access is public. IAM user has full access to S3
I will be very thankful to you for your precious time and help.

```
CORS Policy

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

```
Bucket Policy
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1603207554013",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1603207062804",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::django-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1603207552031",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::085459706277:user/django_user"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::django-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::django-bucket"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

```
settings.py

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
# s3 static settings
STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{STATIC_LOCATION}/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'stock_app.storage_backends.StaticStorage'
# s3 public media settings
PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'stock_app.storage_backends.PublicMediaStorage'
```

```
storage_backends.py

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.conf import settings


class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'
    default_acl = 'public-read'


class PublicMediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    default_acl = 'public-read'
    file_overwrite = False
```

```
models.py

class Upload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='data base')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.file} Success'
```

```
forms.py

class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ['file']
```

```
views.py

@login_required
def upload_file(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['file'] 
            output = files_to_database(file) 

            if not output: #checks to see if file is not already in database 
                form.save()
            
            return redirect('upload')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        

    return render(request, 'stock_app/upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

There problem was in bucket policy. Found the answer on this site:
https://testdriven.io/blog/storing-django-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3/
The policy which worked for me is:

```
Bucket Policy

{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```